# What is the function $f$ such that $(x + f(x))^\alpha = x^\alpha + a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the function $f$ such that $(x + f(x))^\alpha = x^\alpha + a$, with $\alpha,a > 0$.

Comment: On the surface, $f(x) = (x^{\alpha} + a)^{1/\alpha} - x$, but we really know nothing about the domain of $f$.

Comment: As $ \alpha,a > 0 $, we can assume that $ \text{Dom}(f) = [0,\infty) $.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: It is impossible to deduce the existence of $ f $ without knowing what it looks like in the first place. Hence, we are assuming that there exists a function $ f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ x + f(x) \in [0,\infty) $ and $ (x + f(x))^{1/\alpha} = x^{\alpha} + a $ for all $ x \in [0,\infty) $. Such an $ f $ must be of the form given by rlgordonma and Rustyn. We then verify that $ f $ is indeed a valid solution.

Comment: @Rustyn: Yes. I was just assuming a common domain that works for all $ \alpha > 0 $. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying the logarithm to both sides of the equation we have:
$$
\ln{(x+f(x))}=\frac{\ln{(x^{\alpha}+a})}{\alpha} \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
f(x) = (x^{\alpha}+a)^{1/\alpha} - x
$$

#### Added

The domain of $f$ depends on the value of $\alpha$. 
e.g. 
$$
\alpha = n\in \mathbb{N}  \Rightarrow \text{Dom}(f) = (-\infty,\infty)
$$
We are assuming an unprescribed "precalculus" domain that "works", i.e. the output: $f(x)$ will be a real number given any $x \in \text{Dom}(f)$ .   
 
 
Or like Haskell said in the comments, a common blanketed domain that "works" for all $\alpha > 0$ would be: $\text{Dom}(f) = [0,\infty)$. I like this, and think this is more satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my comment up there, I didn't understand it at first.